# LINQ groupBy with multiple columns from string array

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I have the following code:

```
string[] tokens; //columns which I want to groupBy (e.g., storeID, location)
Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>> dictShort = null; // what I want to return
switch (tokens.Length)
{
    case 1:
        dictShort = dsShort.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(x => x[block])
            .Where(g => exp.GroupSizeOk((uint)g.Count()))
            .OrderBy(g => g.Count())
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key.ToString(), g => g.ToList());
        break;
    case 2:
        dictShort = (Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>>)
            dsShort.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(x => x[tokens[0]], x => x[tokens[1]])
            .Where(g => exp.GroupSizeOk((uint)g.Count()))
            .OrderBy(g => g.Count())
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key.ToString(), g => g.ToList());
            // NOT COMPILING> cannot convert Dictionary<string, List<objet>>
            // to Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>>
        break;
    case 3:
        dictShort = (Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>>)
            dsShort.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(x => new { x[tokens[0]], x[tokens[1]], x[tokens[2]]})
            .Where(g => exp.GroupSizeOk((uint)g.Count()))
            .OrderBy(g => g.Count())
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key.ToString(), g => g.ToList());
           // NOT COMPILING: invalid anonymous type member declarator
        break;
}
```

My questions:

(1) Case 3 is not working, how can I correct it?

(2) Can I make this dynamic? (i.e., a foreach or something similar, so that it works with any number of colunms)

```
public bool GroupSizeOk(UInt32 size)
{
    return (size >= _minGroupSize) 
        && (_maxGroupSize > 0 ? size <= _maxGroupSize : true);
}
```

Comment: I just discovered that case2 is also not compiling.

Comment: When you say "not working", do not assume that anyone knows how it is *supposed* to work, or understands how it is broken. Please be specific about what you expect, and how the program is not doing what you think it should be doing.

Comment: I am going to make an edit to your code in case 3.  You have the 'new' in the wrong place.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, sorry for being too generic. By not working I mean the syntax is not correcting and the code is not compiling.

Comment: @ThinkingSites, ops. Misscliked. Thanks.

Comment: If the code doesn't compile you should post why. What's the error? What's GroupSizeOk() as well? Without knowing, I'd say to give the anonomous type in the group by names. so: new { a = x[tokens[0]], b = .... )

Comment: @Paul, Paul I have edited the text to show the compiling erros.

Comment: @Paul, I ahve included code for the GroupSizeOk function. Sorry for not posting it in the first place.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I jsut found the awnswer:

```
 dictShort = dsShort.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
// This where selects elements if and only if all fields are not null
.Where(x => ListAnd(tokens.Select(t => x[t] != DBNull.Value && IsFilledIn(x[t].ToString())).ToArray()))
.GroupBy(x => String.Join("+", tokens.Select(t => x[t].ToString()).ToArray()))
//.GroupBy(x => x[block]) // TODO
.Where(g => exp.GroupSizeOk((uint)g.Count()))
.OrderBy(g => g.Count())
.ToDictionary(g => g.Key/*.ToString()*/, g => g.ToList());
```

Comment: But the size of the array isn't known at compile time.

Comment: You are right, the switch in the code exists to select the corrected implemented version of the groupBy.

Comment: One of the points of the question is to generalize this so you don't have to use the case statement anymore.

Comment: And that's not a particularly sustainable or maintainable option.  You should simply provide a means of grouping on an actual collection instead.

Comment: I agree with you both, but for my case this switch is now the best option.

Comment: @Servy, are our solutions equal?

Comment: @thalesfc No, yours is particularly fragile in the type of input it can support.  For example, imagine what would happen when the items have `+` characters in their string values, or what if the string values don't accurately represent the identity of the object (either where different items have the same string representation, which is going to be the case for any type that doesn't override `ToString`, or where different items have the same string representation, which could happen if there are characteristics of the item not represented in its identity).

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an `IEqualityComparer` for your array that will compare the arrays based on the items in them, rather than by the reference to the array itself.  Such a comparer is simple enough to create:

```
public class SequenceComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    private IEqualityComparer<T> itemComparer;
    public SequenceComparer(IEqualityComparer<T> itemComparer = null)
    {
        this.itemComparer = itemComparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    }
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return obj.Aggregate(79, 
                (hash, next) => hash * 39 + next.GetHashCode());
        }
    }
}
```

Now your query will basically work as you intended it to work, with one other key change being transforming your array `tokens` into an array representing the values from that row that are in the given array:

```
var dictShort = dsShort.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(row => tokens.Select(token => row[token]).ToArray(),
                new SequenceComparer<object>())
            .Where(g => exp.GroupSizeOk((uint)g.Count()))
            .OrderBy(g => g.Count())
            .ToDictionary(g => string.Join(", ", g.Key), g => g.ToList());
```

Comment: I am sorry @Servy, but you have not used the tokens array which contains the field which I want to use as group by fields.

Comment: @thalesfc Right, see edit.

Comment: When I include ur GroupBy I receive the following message: "the type argument cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments"

Comment: @thalesfc I didn't update the comparer to use the one that I defined earlier when I edited the post.

Answer (score -1):

You had:

```
        .GroupBy(new x => { x[tokens[0]], x[tokens[1]], x[tokens[2]]})
```

But it should really be :

```
        .GroupBy(x => string.Join(",",new [] { x[tokens[0]], x[tokens[1]], x[tokens[2]]}))
```

I had made the change in your question before I realized that this is part of your answer.  The new goes inside of the lambda.

As for making the code dynamic based on columns, yes you can.

```
        .GroupBy(x => string.Join(",",tokens.Where(w => w.Columns.Contains(w)).Select(s => x[s]).ToArray()))
```

That should give you a grouping of all the matching columns in the array.

Comment: That still won't work as you need to name the anonymous type properties.

Comment: In general you shouldn't make changes to incorrect code in questions because it may invalidate the question itself.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that error after someone pointed it out on the original post.  I changed it to an array.

Comment: @Show Yes, I also realized my error after the fact on that too.

Comment: You can't group by arrays.

Comment: You could hack around the group limitation with a string.join("", tokens) to produce a key from the array elements

Comment: @ThinkingSites, thanks you solition works :). I have not understand the dynamic solution, can you please explain it more?

Comment: Sure.  When grouping the array, you're matching the columns that exist to the tokens, and using that to create your group by key.  Since you're not using the group-by key in any significant way, you can leave it as is to compile your data in the further selects.  To Enigmativity's point, if the arrays don't work as a key use string.join like atom.gregg said. Again, since you're not using the key values, you can transform it however you like.  Does that help?

Comment: Hmm it helped. Why is not possible to do something like this: GroupBy(x => new[] { foreach token in tokens {x[tokens]}}) ?

Comment: Well, in a way that's what I did.  The Select statement does a foreach loop and grabs each token.  What you posted isn't valid C#, though I get your concept.

Comment: @ThinkingSites I just tested ur solution with the new [] {..}. the code compiles, however it is no grouping data accordingly.

Comment: @thalesfc - As I said above you can't group by arrays. The code compiles and runs, but it doesn't group. That why people have suggested the `String.Join` method to create a groupable string key.

Comment: @ThinkingSites - You really should edit your answer to remove the grouping by array. It doesn't work an it makes this answer quite terrible as many people will now waste their time writing incorrect code.